# Homotopy type of space of embeddings of a disk

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, smooth-manifolds

Let $M^n$ be a smooth $n$-dimensional manifold and let $\mathbb{D}^n$ be the open unit disk in $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Consider the space $\text{Emb}(\mathbb{D}^n,M^n)$ of smooth embeddings of $\mathbb{D}^n$ into $M^n$, equipped with the $C^{\infty}$ topology.  Letting $\text{Fr}(M^n)$ be the bundle of frames of the tangent bundle of $M^n$, there is a map $\Psi\colon \text{Emb}(\mathbb{D}^n,M^n) \rightarrow \text{Fr}(M^n)$ taking an embedding $f\colon \mathbb{D}^n \rightarrow M^n$ to the point $f(0) \in M^n$ equipped with the image of the standard framing of $T_0 \mathbb{D}^n = \mathbb{R}^n$ under the derivative $D_0 f\colon T_0 \mathbb{D}^n \rightarrow T_{f(0)} M^n$.

For a paper I'm writing, I'm looking for a reference proving that $\Psi$ is a homotopy equivalence.  I know several proofs of this, but all of them have slightly annoying aspects (at least if you write out all the details) so I would prefer to just give a reference.

Comment: There is the lecture notes, Diffeomorphism groups of manifolds by Alexander Kupers

Comment: @DanielH.Hartman: The version of that I have is about 330 pages.  Do you know where this result can be found in it?

Comment: chapter 9, page 73.

Comment: @DanielH.Hartman: Thanks!